# Чтения файла и сохранения в json

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день.
Есть файл test1 его содержимое:

```
!Сколько будет 2 + 2?
-5
-6
+4
-3
#
!Сколько будет 2 + 3?
-5
+6
-4
-3
#
!Кто такой Александ Македонский?
-гаплит
+величайший завоеватель всех времен
-Цезарь
-Сын Зевса
```

Правильно ли у меня составлена логика? 
Если в файле знак !-это вопрос
- Не правильный ответ
+ правильный ответ
"#" - новый вопрос, стирается список с ответами

Скрипт чтения файла:

```
import json


with open("test1", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    with open("test.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        question_test = dict()
        answer_list = list()
        for line in file.readlines():
            if line[0] == "!":
                qwestion = line
                question_test[qwestion] = []
            elif line[0] == "-":
                false_answer = line
                answer_list.append(false_answer)
                negative_answer = line
            elif line[0] == "+":
                tru_anser = line
                answer_list.append(tru_anser)
            elif line[0] == "#":
                del answer_list[:]
            question_test[qwestion] = answer_list
        json.dump(question_test, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Сама проблема состоит в том при сохранение в json у меня получается такой результат:

```
{
  "!Кто такой Александ Македонский?\n": [
    "-гаплит\n",
    "+величайший завоеватель всех времен\n",
    "-Цезарь\n",
    "-Сын Зевса"
  ],
  "!Сколько будет 2 + 2?\n": [
    "-гаплит\n",
    "+величайший завоеватель всех времен\n",
    "-Цезарь\n",
    "-Сын Зевса"
  ],
  "!Сколько будет 2 + 3?\n": [
    "-гаплит\n",
    "+величайший завоеватель всех времен\n",
    "-Цезарь\n",
    "-Сын Зевса"
  ]
}
```

т.е ключь создается а значения только последнего вопроса в файле. Нужен пинок от более опытных коллег)). Спасибо

Comment: Сколько будет 2 + 3? Проверьте правильный ответ ...

Comment: Спасибо, за замечание.

Comment: @LexHobbit Бывает XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например такой алгоритм (всегда проще в таких случая с нуля написать, чем в чужом коде разбираться):

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict


question_test = defaultdict(list)

with open('test', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # Защита от дурака которая проверяет чтобы в файле сначала была 
    # строка с вопросом
    question = None

    for line in f:
        # Удаление ' ', '\n', '\t', '\r' из начала и конца строки
        line = line.strip()

        # Защита от дурака которая проверяет чтобы строка не была пустой 
        if not line:
            continue

        type_line = line[0]
        if type_line == '!':
            question = line[1:]
            continue

        if type_line not in '-+':
            continue

        if not question:
            continue

        question_test[question].append(line)


json_data = json.dumps(question_test, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

---

Если важен порядок вопросов, тогда нужно использовать `OrderedDict` (не актуально, начиная с 3.6 версии, т.к. `dict` сохраняет порядок ключей):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
question_test = OrderedDict()

with open('test', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # Защита от дурака которая проверяет чтобы в файле сначала была
    # строка с вопросом
    question = None

    for line in f:
        # Удаление ' ', '\n', '\t', '\r' из начала и конца строки
        line = line.strip()

        # Защита от дурака которая проверяет чтобы строка не была пустой
        if not line:
            continue

        type_line = line[0]
        if type_line == '!':
            question = line[1:]
            continue

        if type_line not in '-+':
            continue

        if not question:
            continue

        if question not in question_test:
            question_test[question] = list()

        question_test[question].append(line)


import json
json_data = json.dumps(question_test, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

---

Консоль:

```
{
    "Сколько будет 2 + 2?": [
        "-5",
        "-6",
        "+4",
        "-3"
    ],
    "Сколько будет 2 + 3?": [
        "-5",
        "+6",
        "-4",
        "-3"
    ],
    "Кто такой Александ Македонский?": [
        "-гаплит",
        "+величайший завоеватель всех времен",
        "-Цезарь",
        "-Сын Зевса"
    ]
}
```